# How does the Speaker vote if there is a tie?

Tags: united-kingdom, speaker

If there is a tie in a vote, how does the Speaker vote? Does the Speaker conventionally vote with the Government?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Ties are rare, but one happened recently, prompting this question to be explored [in parliament](https://youtu.be/s3oteTu-jkY) and in the press. By tradition, the Speaker votes for any proposal (be it from the government or not) in a procedural vote in order to allow further discussion. However, in the final vote, the Speaker votes against it, on the reasoning that he or she should not create a majority where there is none.